# Symfony2: simplest way to get RESTful urls

Tags: rest, routes, symfony

Currently I have the usual Controller/Action structure:

BlogController:

```
/blog/list  
/blog/create  
/blog/detail/my-blog-hash
```

And PostController

```
/post/create  
/post/detail/my-post-hash
```

What I would like is a URL for the blog post detail view:

```
/blog/detail/my-blog-hash/post/my-post-hash
```

I know there is a RESTBundle, but this is overcomplicating things IMO and there are some real issues with routes and form validation which I was not able to solve (even with help of the guys on IRC).
I don't need accesspoints for JSON, serializers, special views etc., I just need a way to stack controllers somehow.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What you're asking makes no logical sense. You can't have two controllers process a request and then return a response. You **could** pass it to the `BlogController` and then forward it onto the `PostController` after that, but you'd be far better using one controller and making it responsible for whatever the action is meant to do.

Comment: @Jaitsu I don't ask for a way to handle one request with multiple controllers. I don't care how the routing works. What I want is a RESTful url structure and a way to structure controllers so that blog stuff can be handled by the BlogController and post stuff can be handled from the PostController

Comment: I misunderstood the original question. What's the problem with just defining two separate routes then?

Comment: @Jaitsu No real problem actually. But there's some overhead to handle manually: you have to retrieve the parent object (the blog) in each subcontroller action, and look whether the the post is a valid child of it. Then think of deeper hierarchies- there will be quite some overhead: parameters in views and actions, retrieving objects, validating the relations- these are things which should be handled by the/some framework IMO. But sometimes it's better to stick to the pragmatic way- thanks for reminding me of it! You could write some illustrating lines and I will give you the bounty for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed RestBundle, after playing around several hours I removed it again, due to the inflexibility of the routes (at least I did not find out how to set the routes accordingly).

After that I set the routes just like in common controllers. So I added routing annotations like that:

```
// BlogController
@ORM\Route("blogs/{blogHash}", name="blog_detail")
public function detailAction(Blog $blog)
```

And:

```
// PostController
@ORM\Route("blogs/{blogHash}/post/{postHash}", name="blog_post_detail")
public function detailAction($blogHash, $postHash)
```

Important: you have to include the PostController before the BlogController in your routing configuration

Comment: @maiwald: yeah, I know, nothing special. I was hoping for a more "elegant" solution. However, I added those couple of lines just for matters of completeness.

Answer (score 8):

This doesn't answer your specific question but I wanted to recommend a cleaner URL design that is more RESTful.

To work with blogs in general interact with the `/blogs` base resource.

`POST /blogs` to create a blog.

`GET /blogs` to list all the blogs.

To work with a specific blog you then specify which blog.

`GET /blogs/:id` to get the details for the specific blog.

Now specific which subresource of blogs you want to interact with.

`POST /blogs/:id/posts` to create a new post.

`GET /blogs/:id/posts/:id` to get details of a specific post for a specific blog.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking RESTfully, you have two resources: blogs and posts.

In a RESTful route, the action is implied by the http verb. I understand you are not in Rails, but these simple tables illustrate the "Rails way" of doing REST and RESTful nested resources:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Very clean.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just map a route with two parameters to the detail action?

We are using annotations for our routes so thats what I know :) But I suppose the gist of it is the same for all methods.

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog/{blog_hash}/post/{post_hash}", name="post_detail")
 */
```

The 'problem' then is that you have to fetch the post's blog to pass the two arguments to the URL helper when showing links to it and not just the post itself. But I don't think there is any other way.

The detail action has to check then that the given url is valid. I doubt that sf2 will do that for you.

Comment: This is indeed possible. the problem is that you have the whole code in one controller. I want the PostController to handle the post stuff and the BlogController to do the blog stuff.

Comment: very true. and i'd love to know how to do that cleanly myself!